# Is there a way to format git log after git commend such as `git push`?

Tags: git

As you know, after enter git commend in the shell, you will get log, for example: 
[image: [enter image description here]

and if I can format these log so I can get more important information and ignore unimportant information?

Comment: what you want to do? store it in some files or what?

Comment: pipe command will help you

Comment: @Gahan i don't want to store it, what i want to do is just simplify the log and  retain more important info.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can change the format/output of [`git push`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push) itself.

What you can do is parse its output, extract the commits pushed, and apply a `git log` (with any format you want) on said commits in order to list what was pushed.